# Unacknowledged messages alert creation in google stack driver

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-stackdriver

Does stackdriver have alert mechanism?
like if i see more than 1000 unacknowledged messages then alert need to be placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with Stackdriver. In the [Monitoring Alerting page](https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting), click on Create Policy:

[image: Create Policy]

Then, click on "Add Condition" on the next page. To create the correct condition, select "Cloud Pub/Sub Subscription" as the resource:

[image: Subscription]

For metric, choose "Unacked messages":

[image: Metric]

Under "Configuration" you can then set the threshold to 1000:

[image: Threshold]

Once you click "Add," you can now configure the rest of the parts of the alert as you could any other Stackdriver alert by choosing who should be notified and the documentation and name of the alert.

Comment: Is there any cost involved in it for this alert?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#limits), there are no charges for using alerting.